# iText DITO - How can I use a fields Data name as a reference in a calculation?

Tags: itext

In iText's DITO template designer product, I have one field which has a fairly complex calculation. In another field, I want to use the result of that calculation.

The tooltip says "Identifier used for referencing fields in calculation expressions". So I assumed if I named it `blah` I can use it in a calculation in another field like this: `sum({{blah}},42)` (e.g. add 42 to the value of blah). But if I do that I get the error

```
Unable to resolve reference: "{{blah}}" in node with tag: <span> and text:
```

[image: itext-dito-properties]

The iText DITO documentation does not elaborate on this feature at all. I'm evaluating iText DITO and there does not seem to be any way to get support while evaluating the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a field with a very complex calculation. In order to reuse the calculation result, I can do the following:

1. Give a name to this field (in the image below I've chosen name "total")
   [image]
2. Insert a calculation to another field (where I want to reuse "total")
   [image]
3. Add "total" as the calculation's body:
   [image: List item]

That's it, now the total value is reused:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've been in meetings all day and just tried this out before reading your response and could not believe it worked. I assumed I had to use the curly brace syntax because the docs don't explicitly show an example of this. Appreciate the response!

Comment: Strangely, my UI looks slightly different. I do not have a "Name" field at the same level as the calculation. I do have a "Name" field at the whole element level (e.g. at the Rich Text component level). In your example you're getting the numeric value 114399. I can only attach a Name to the Rich Text component which has the *formatted* value $114399. I cannot do any math on it like sum(total,42). My UI looks like the image israelgarcia posted below.

Comment: For more context, I'm using likely the latest version:

iText DITO Editor 2.5.3
Built on January 9, 2023

I believe I can make it work by doing all calculations with the data type number instead of currency in hidden fields and then formatting as currency where needed. I also have to make sure I uncheck "Use thousand separator"!!  It does make it a bit more cumbersome. And I worry now upgrading may break templates if a feature in earlier versions behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation you are looking for is at https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/ditokb/latest/manuals/itext-dito-editor/calculations

You have to give the rich text element a name in the properties to be able to reference it on other rich text element and/or calculations.

See image example at https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/ditokb/files/latest/68620314/68620309/1/1660291029000/image2020-5-27_17-56-41.png

Comment: Thanks your exactly right. I missed the blurb at the bottom: "Note that you don't use double curly braces to refer to this named field. the double curly braces are only used to refer to elements in the data sample. "